# Is there an advantage by passing std::array on the stack for API call

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I was reading about the key differences between `std::array` and C type array and came to know that one of the key differences is that C type array when called to an API go as a pointer while a copy of `std::array` gets passed. One of the blogs mentioned that as an advantage but I don't think so. What are the key advantages of using an `std::array` over C-type array? My exploration and understanding suggests that almost everything can be done with C type arrays. They can even be passed to STL algorithms. So I don't see any key advantage of using `std::array` over C-type array. Is that actually so?

Comment: _The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc._ (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: It's also easier to compare `std::array` objects to each other, since the standard comparison operators are overloaded for `std::array`. And regarding the copying of `std::array` when passing by value, then don't? Use references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that everything you can do with `std::array` could be done with C array. Actually, `std::array` simply wraps a fixed size C array internally. However, `std::array` is often more convenient.

Ability to pass an array by value *is* an advantage. If you'd like to do this with C array, you'd have to pass a pointer and size and then create local copy. With `std::array`, you can avoid this, and choose what better suits your needs:

```
void takeArrayByValue(std::array<int, 5> arr)
{
    arr[0] = newValue; // arr is a local copy, caller does not see this
}

void takeArrayByReference(std::array<int, 5>& arr)
{
     arr[0] = newValue; // variable passed as argument is modified
}

// compare with this:
void takeCArrayAndMakeLocalCopy(const int (&arr)[5])
{
    int localArr[5];
    std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), localArr);

   // do something with localArr
}
```

---

Another thing: it's easier to misuse C arrays:

```
void takeCAray(int arr[5]);

int arr[3];
takeCArray(arr); // compiles
```

In this example, `takeCArray` really takes a pointer. It should have been `takeCArray(int (&arr)[5])`, but compiler won't complain about this, and the bug can potentially stay unnoticed at first. This can't happen with `std::array`:

```
void takeStdArray(std::array<int, 5>& arr);

std::array<int, 3> arr;
takeStdArray(arr); // compiler error!
```